# Freeze after wakeup with GDM Wayland on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: suspend, 17.10, gnome-shell, wayland

It appears that using Xorg instead of Wayland is the only way to fix this problem on Ubuntu 17.10. For some odd reason, whenever I wake my computer from suspend using Gnome in a Wayland session, my screen freezes completely on whatever was last up before suspending and I can't get any IO response at all. It literally necessitates restarting my computer. This problem is nonexistent when using Xorg instead of Wayland with GDM. Anyone else have this issue on 17.10 or figure out a solution better than simply switching to Xorg? I should clarify that I am not using nvidia drivers, I'm using Intel integrated graphics on a core-i7 5500U.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it seemed that GDM was the problem.  I went back to LightDM, using:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

And things are behaving better.  At least in this regard...

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?
How does your last sentence adress the OP's question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same issue. Didn't think it was related to wayland.
Although, if I wait few minutes, it comes back (just tried).

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this issue too, but I'm not on Wayland - I'm on the NVidia Xorg session (I installed proprietary NVidia drivers shortly after installing Ubuntu 17.10). I'm having the same issue with GDM.

If I leave my PC locked for long enough, when I come back to it, I see a GDM lock screen with a plain white background, but I seem to have bee logged out at at stage because it's on the default display settings (I have the UI scaled at 200% whenever I am logged in). At this point, either:
- the session has crashed and is unresponsive (I can move my mouse cursor around but no response to any clicks or any combination of keyboard presses); or
- I can unlock the lock screen with my password, and then I subsequently get *another* GDM lock screen, this time one with my UI scaling and background, which I have to unlock with password again (but when I do, it's clear that I've been logged out, because all my running apps have been killed).

If I do not lock my PC and turn off auto-blank screen, I can leave the PC for hours and come back to it and it's still running just fine with no problems.

I changed "SUSPEND_METHODS=" to "none" in /etc/default/acpi-support and thought this had resolved the issue, but came back to another "white screen" today...

Incidentally I had a similar issue when I installed Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 on my NUC earlier this year. I never found a fix, but it seemed to get resolved with updates to the distro, so I'm hoping the same happens with 17.10!